# .htaccess redirect non-existing pages only, keeping the token

Tags: .htaccess

I want to redirect

> www.domain.com/abc

to

> www.domain.com/index.php?a=abc

only if the folder abc doesn't already exist. 
How should I write the .htaccess file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/index.php?a=$1 [L]
```

Comment: it redrected to index.php?a=/abc