# how to link css to php in MVC?

Tags: php, css, model-view-controller

I am working on a MVC framework with php I have an index.php file inside the the app/views folder and I want to link my css to this index.php but for some reasons it is not working. this is the structure of my app:

[image]

and this is the .htaccess file in public folder

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options -Multiviews
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /mvc-framework/public
  RewriteRule  ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

also this is my index.php file inside views:

```php
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo URL_ROOT;?>/public/css/style.css" />    
</head>
<body>
<!-- URL_ROOT variable defined like this:define('URL_ROOT','http://localhost/mvc-framework'); -->
    <h1><?php echo URL_ROOT?></h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [.htaccess redirect non-existing pages only, keeping the token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13264690/htaccess-redirect-non-existing-pages-only-keeping-the-token)

Comment: In order to load the css file, just write this: `<link href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />` (with folder `public` beeing the _document root_ and the first slash character ("/") in the `href` attribute pointing to the _document root_, e.g. to `public`).